# 404 in gutenberg autosave of a Custom Post Type with custom rest_namespace

Tags: block-editor, rest-api, autosave

I'm having some troubles with CPTs defined with custom `rest_namespace` at `register_post_type`. I keep getting an 404 error at the console. The error shows that the namespace is not being changed in autosave route.

WP default namespace: `wp/v2`

Custom namespace defined: `ek/v1`

I dug into the core classes to find how Wordpress handle custom namespace.

The `WP_REST_Autosaves_Controler` define the `namespace` using `get_post_type_object` at the `__construct` method:

```
...
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $parent_post_type );
....
$this->namespace = ! empty( $post_type_object->rest_namespace ) ? $post_type_object->rest_namespace : 'wp/v2';
...
```

If I do a discovery request at the `ek/v1` I can see the endpoints registered correctly:

```
"/ek/v1/releases/(?P<parent>[\\d]+)/autosaves/(?P<id>[\\d]+)"
```

But in the console this error pops up:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/releases/70/autosaves?context=edit&_locale=user 404 (Not Found)
```

So, why the default namespace persist if I did all right?
Would it be some javascript function of wordpress that would be doing the request on the incorrect route? What function? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: can you add some context for why you're trying to change the `wp/v2` namespace to `ek/v1`? As well as the PHP code you've used to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, why the default namespace persist if I did all right? Would it be some javascript function of wordpress that would be doing the request on the incorrect route? What function? How to fix it?

If the endpoint works then you changed it correctly, but if you've flushed rewrite rules/permalinks, and it still isn't working, then you need to raise a bug with the Gutenberg github, or the official WP Trac.

Note that this is assuming you're only trying to change the REST API endpoint of a single custom post type, and doing it via `register_post_type` and the `rest_namespace` parameter with WP 5.9/6 or higher.

Otherwise, it looks based on this code that you have found a WordPress/Gutenberg bug with retrieving autosaves:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/c0df23894233e851f3fe734358831ad560a18448/packages/core-data/src/resolvers.js#L332

Comment: At the time of writing there is some awareness of this parameters in Gutenberg https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5ad090d7f5eb1f794f7dfc7a447b29a7be083a14/packages/core-data/src/entities.ts#L444-L448 and has been for at least 7 months now, if you're not on 6.0 I would upgrade immediately

Comment: I've created a PR to try and fix this, totally untested though https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/41542 ***and you should still create a ticket on the Gutenberg GitHub as quickly as possible***. It's very likely my fix will be rejected for not having a ticket

Comment: I'm using 6.1-alpha version, and I did flush rewrite. How can I test your PR? I'll open a ticket in trac. Thanks!

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/55915#ticket

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, since you've created a PR to correct it